# How to set key value of array in jquery

Tags: html, jquery, arrays, dictionary, key

I have this really ugly bit of code that sets the key => value of the menu_items array. I would like to use the map function to set the key and value from the ul but couldn't work it out so resorted to this.

How can I use the map function to set key and value for menu_items?

```js
function ClothingSetup(clothing) {
  var menu_items = {};
  menu_items["hat"] = "hat";
  menu_items["mask"] = "mask";
  menu_items["coat"] = "coat";
  menu_items["shirt"] = "shirt";
  menu_items["gloves"] = "gloves";
  menu_items["pants"] = "pants";
  menu_items["boots"] = "boots";
  menu_items["bandana"] = "bandana";

  $.each(clothing, function(index, item) {
    if (index == menu_items[index] && item > 1) {
      $('#' + index).toggleClass("active");
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="nav-cat" id="hat" value="1"><img src="/html/img/hat.png"></li>
  <li class="nav-cat" id="mask" value="1"><img src="/html/img/mask.png"></li>
  <li class="nav-cat" id="coat" value="1"><img src="/html/img/coat.png"></li>
  <li class="nav-cat" id="shirt" value="1"><img src="/html/img/shirt.png"></li>
  <li class="nav-cat" id="gloves" value="1"><img src="/html/img/gloves.png"></li>
  <li class="nav-cat" id="pants" value="1"><img src="/html/img/pants.png"></li>
  <li class="nav-cat" id="boots" value="1"><img src="/html/img/boots.png"></li>
  <li class="nav-cat" id="bandana" value="1"><img src="/html/img/bandanna.png"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .map like this

LIs do not have `value` by the way

```js
const items = $(".nav-cat").map(function() { return {item: this.dataset.item,value:this.dataset.value} }).get()

console.log(items)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="nav-cat" data-item="hat" data-value="1"><img src="/html/img/hat.png"></li>
  <li class="nav-cat" data-item="mask" data-value="1"><img src="/html/img/mask.png"></li>
  <li class="nav-cat" data-item="coat" data-value="1"><img src="/html/img/coat.png"></li>
  <li class="nav-cat" data-item="shirt" data-value="1"><img src="/html/img/shirt.png"></li>
  <li class="nav-cat" data-item="gloves" data-value="1"><img src="/html/img/gloves.png"></li>
  <li class="nav-cat" data-item="pants" data-value="1"><img src="/html/img/pants.png"></li>
  <li class="nav-cat" data-item="boots" data-value="1"><img src="/html/img/boots.png"></li>
  <li class="nav-cat" data-item="bandana" data-value="1"><img src="/html/img/bandanna.png"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you!  Chose your response as the answer due to using map, I'll update li's to use data-value.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over all `<li>`s and extract their ID, and from that, put them onto the `menu_items` object:

```
const menu_items = {};
for (const elm of document.querySelectorAll('li')) {
  menu_items[elm.id] = elm.id;
}
```

But IDs should probably be reserved for things that are *absolutely unique*, not for similar repeating elements like list items. If you need the string, I'd recommend putting it into a data attribute instead, eg

```
<li data-name="hat"
```

and extract it with

```
const menu_items = {};
for (const elm of document.querySelectorAll('li')) {
  const { name } = elm.dataset;
  menu_items[name] = name;
}
```